# How would I store a daily value on the server side of my website

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a small daily web game, I currently have it generate the answer of the day using a pRNG seeded based on the date picking the day's answer out of a database of possible answers. I want to store a small file of the last 30-60 days answers so that I can modify my random answer generation to prevent duplicate days too close to one another.

```
function splitmix32(a) {
    return function() {
        a |= 0; a = a + 0x9e3779b9 | 0;
        var t = a ^ a >>> 16; t = Math.imul(t, 0x21f0aaad);
            t = t ^ t >>> 15; t = Math.imul(t, 0x735a2d97);
        return ((t = t ^ t >>> 15) >>> 0) / 4294967296;
    }
}

function generateAnsOfTheDay(){
    let now = new Date();
    let epochDays = Math.floor(now/8.64e7);
    console.log("Epoch Day: " + epochDays);
    let randomNumber = splitmix32(epochDays)();
    //check number of digits in the float randomNumber
    var length = (randomNumber + '').replace('.', '').length;
    //multiply float randomNumber by 10^x where x is the number of digits minus one, this converts the number to a integer
    randomNumber = randomNumber*Math.pow(10, length-1)
    console.log(randomNumber)
    let ansNumber= randomNumber%ansList.length
    console.log(ansNumber)
    console.log(ansList[ansNumber].ansName);
    return Math.floor(ansNumber);
}
```

I then just use the output of that function as the index to pull out of the json file of all possible answers. It works perfectly other than the potential of repeat answers (which I confirmed are regularly occurring enough to be a problem in my eyes)

What would be the best way to store a list of the past x days answers? I believe can pretty easily adjust my generation function to account for repeats, if I was able to store it easily. I don't really know how to make sure that it adds the newest days answer and removes the least recent one each day on the server side.

Comment: `I want to store a small file` then do so with whatever server side framework you use